# zoom Bitmap image on Canvas with finger spread

Tags: android

I am drawing a bitmap  a on canvas using

```
 canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);
```

and now i want to zoom this bitmap on multi touch with two finger . i have found zoom image solution with one finger on  [This page](http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/) , but i want to do this with two finger (pinch zoom) .How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [andriod-multitouch-controller](http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/). It's an amazing library that gives you pinch zooming. It makes multitouch easier and makes it very smooth. I've used it on a mapping app and it works great. Also supports panning and multi-touch rotation if you want it.

Comment: i didn't get the solution . i want to zoom only bitmap image . but it is so complicated . is there any alternative ?

Comment: Multi-touch anything is pretty complicated. That library makes things so much easier. The source includes a sample application, so implementation should be very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yoy have to implements onTouchListener on canvas View .

```
private String  mode= "Down";
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mode="DOWN";
    }
    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

            if(mode.equals("DRAG"){
                 // it means both fingers are pressed and now you can zoom the canvas 
             }

    }
           else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN){

           mode="DRAG";

    }


    return false;
}
```

So then you can wrte your code there to zoom canvas , now you have to write code for canvas in matrix for zooming in bitmap .